# Standard format for representing large graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, data-sets

I am aware of the ["famous" DIMACS graph format](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/) (which frankly looks a little clunky to me - "c" for a comment line ?) and the [METIS file format](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/metis_graph/metis_graph.html).

While it's not particularly hard to invent my own graph format, it's nice to follow something accepted so that reuse of code for generating examples and testing algorithms is easier.

> Is there a standard accepted format for representing graphs for use
>   with testing graph algorithms ?

Comment: I forgot about LEDA. In fact there's also the GML format.

Comment: Brendan McKay's [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) package uses [graph6 and sparse6 formats](http://mapleta.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/g6.html).

Comment: For large graphs of million nodes and billion edges such as twitter, the input and output time will be significant and I think it is much faster to use binary formats. I am not aware of any well-known binary format thought.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there's a single standard format. igraph library (http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) could be of use, however, as it supports reading/writing of number of different graph formats.